# how to install ZIP (ZZIPlib) for PHP on CentOS

Tags: php, centos, compression

I have Cent OS 5 and want to install ZIP or ZIPlib extension i tried to look it up using YUM utility and its not there how can i install it?

Answer (score 1):

There is php-pecl-zip (1.8.10) package on EPEL [additional repository](http://wiki.centos.org/AdditionalResources/Repositories).

Answer (score 0):

You can also install the php-devel package via yum and then use the pecl command to install pecl extensions. It should be something like "pecl install zip".